# Angular2 change color of a cell

Tags: angular

Good morning,

My question is about changing the color of a cell in a table.
When it is empty I want it to be yellow, and when I type some value in it change to white.

I had thought of using ngswitch, for each case, and the focus event for when I switch from one cell to another check if it is empty or has a value.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add the code inside your question above, we can see it better there instead of here in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple!

Use ngClass and define two different css class with different background colors, for example:

```
.empty{
  background: yellow;
} 

.content{
  background: white
}
```

In the html you can add something like:

```
<div [ngClass]="cellContent == cellContent ? 'empty': 'content'">
```

Where `cellContent` can be a string that is either empty or has that what you want to show in the cell.

Comment: cellContent must be defined in your Component