# Angular 2 Change color of a cell

Tags: angular

[Reference to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908418/angular2-change-color-of-a-cell/46909229#46909229)

I have a table in which the cell if empty is yellow, but if someone writes in it it changes to white:

[Tabla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyQ00.png)

My question is I already have the html done:

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Fpf.png)

But the component is not how to do to obtain if that cell is empty or not.

How can you get the value to know if that cell is empty or not?

[Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk0eX.png)

Because if it is empty the switch would pass the yellow value and if someone writes when switching to another cell this would become white

Answer (score 0):

I'll try:

1. Put the table into a ReactiveForm
2. Use ngclass and the properties pristine and untouched

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass or ngStyle

I am giving you a solution with ngStyle :

in your HTML change input to this :

```
<input type="text"  [(ngModel)] = "test" [ngStyle]= "{'background-color' : 
test == ''?'yellow' : 'white'}">
```

in your component.ts :
add

```
test = '';
```

you can of course change the variable name and color according to you . I just wanted to give a simple example.

Comment: Yes, but I also want to get the value of that cell if it is not empty

Comment: Yes you can get the value as it's bound to ngModel .. the test variable here will give the value of input

Comment: But it gives me this error: "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"